# How to reuse the call function in r?

Tags: r

Stepwise selection method (**stepAIC** in **MASS** library) provide the subset of variables in its last step. Instead of typing the final model I would like to use it through **call** function. I don't know how to do that! Following is an example:

```
x = as.data.frame(matrix(cbind(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, 10), rnorm(100, 100), rpois(100, 4)), 100, 4))
fit = lm(V1 ~., data=x)
st = stepAIC(fit, direction = "both")
st$call
#  lm(formula = V1 ~ 1, data = x)
```

How to use `st$call` for further use? I tried the following with a hope that it will give me the regression results, but it's not working:

```
fm = st$call
summary(call)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `eval(st$call)`?

Comment: How exactly do you want to use it? The call is just an un-evaulated expression. You can evaluate it with `eval()`: `eval(st$call)`

Comment: @Roland @MrFlick That is it. I did not know the `eval` function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I feel compelled to point out that stepwise regression should be avoided: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection#20856

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse a function call with `eval()`.

```
data(iris)
model <- lm(Sepal.Length~., data = iris)
model
# Call:
#   lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)        Sepal.Width       Petal.Length        Petal.Width  Speciesversicolor   Speciesvirginica  
# 2.1713             0.4959             0.8292            -0.3152            -0.7236            -1.0235  


eval(model$call)
# Call:
#   lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)        Sepal.Width       Petal.Length        Petal.Width  Speciesversicolor   Speciesvirginica  
# 2.1713             0.4959             0.8292            -0.3152            -0.7236            -1.0235
```

As you can see the output of both calls are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The selected model is returned. You can just use `st` directly. The returned object has a little bit more information attached to it since it was the result of the stepwise procedure but the returned object can and should do everything that you'd want to do from fitting that model 'by hand'.